# Is this a constructor problem (referencing deleted function)? (error code C2280)

Tags: c++, constructor, user-defined-types

I have a class ‘Token’ and a class ‘Token_Stream’, as shown in code below. 
When I try to create an object of class Token_Stream, I get a compile error: (C2280) 'Token_stream::Token_stream(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function

I'm using C++ Visual Studio Community 15.9.1. I am new to "modern" programming and teaching myself C++ from Stroustrup's book PPP C++ 2nd edition. I have read many of the results from searching this site for "c++ attempting to reference a deleted function c2280," but none have helped me solve the problem.

My understanding of constructors is incomplete, despite reading several webpages and book sections about them, but I understand enough (I think) to think this is a constructor problem. I am definitely struggling with the user-defined class that includes a member that is another user-defined class plus member functions.

Code is below. If the declarations of the two member functions of Token_stream would be helpful, let me know and I'll add them.

```
class Token {
public:
    char kind;
    double value;
    Token(char ch)    // make a Token from a char 
   //- this is a constructor, right?
        :kind(ch), value(0) { } // what do the braces here mean?
    Token(char ch, double val)     // make a Token from a char and a double
        :kind(ch), value(val) { }
};

class Token_stream {
public:
    Token get();
    void putback(Token t);
private:
    bool full{ false };
    Token buffer;   
//  Token_stream() = default;
};

Token_stream ts;    // ERROR C2280 here
// Token_stream::Token_stream(void)': attempting
// to ref. a deleted function
```

Comment: `Token` doesn't have a default constructor (a constructor that can be called with no arguments). Because of this, `Token_stream` doesn't have one, either - there's no user-defined one, and neither can one be implicitly defined because it would need to construct `buffer` member, but there's no default constructor for it.

Comment: Thank you also for your comment. I did try to make a user-defined constructor for Token_stream, but was unable to figure that out; the void function putback() was giving me trouble. If you wouldn't mind, what would a user-defined constructor for Token_stream look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `Token` class. You don't have a default-constructor of `Token` but you have a member-attribute `Token buffer;` in `Token_stream` which will be initialized on instantiation of `Token_stream`. There is no default constructor for `Token`. Therefore the compiler can't add an default-constructor for `Token_stream`.

gcc 8.2 shows the following error/note:

```
note: 'Token_stream::Token_stream()' is implicitly deleted because the default 
definition would be ill-formed

error: no matching function for call to 'Token::Token()'
```

This shows the problem with creating a default constructor for `Token_stream`.

You can simply add a default-constructor for `Token` and it should work.`enter code here`

Comment: That worked, thanks! I guess I didn't realize I could have a default constructor for 
Token because I already have those two implicitly-defined (is that the right term?) constructors. Yes?

Comment: `Token`s two constructors are *explicitly* defined. The compiler adds a default constructor only when there is no other constructor specified. If he does this is called *implicitly* defined. This is what happens with your `Token_stream` class. There is no constructor provided but the compiler tries to add one. When he does he tries to instantiate the `Buffer` without parameters (the non existent default constructor) which leads to this error. You have two user-defined constructors defined for `Token` so the compiler doesn't add an default one.